# Why does the form not applying to the second TABLE?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to put a DELETE link in the TD section of the TABLE. It seems the form for DELETE is only coming on the first TD in the TABLE but its is not getting linked to the second TD.

**Screenshots and code below**

**PHP Code inside HTML**

```
<?php
$dirlist = getFileList("./tickets/");
foreach($dirlist as $file) {
if($file['type'] != 'text/plain') {
continue;
}
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td><a href=\"{$file['name']}\" data-toggle='tooltip' title='Download File' data-placement='bottom' download>",basename($file['name']),"</a></td>\n";
echo "<td>{$file['type']}</td>\n";
echo "<td>{$file['size']}</td>\n";
echo "<td>",date('r', $file['lastmod']),"</td>\n";
echo "<td>\n";
echo "<form method='POST' action='delete_file.php'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='file_name' value='",basename($file['name']),"'>";
echo "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' name='delete_file' value='Delete'>";
echo "</td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>
```

Screenshot of the TABLE
[image: The form is under DELETE button]

Screenshot of the first TD html code
[image: The form is applied on the first DELETE button]

Screenshot of the second TD html code
[image: The form is not applied on the second DELETE button]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see you closing the form anywhere. You should have a `</form>` before the last `</td>`.

Comment: **Thanks** I never noticed that and now it is solved. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

your form tag is started but not closed
and after submit your form your file_name input duplicate and send first of them all of the time add close form tag same below code to correct response

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='delete_file.php'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='file_name' value='",basename($file['name']),"'>";
echo "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' name='delete_file' value='Delete'>";
echo "</form>" ;
```

Comment: Yes that solved the issue. @magnus-eriksson solved the issue.